Failing image/video upload in application for storing it in AWS S3 bucket
So, I making an application which will take user's input and store it in s3 bucket.
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int VIDEO_PICK_CODE = 1001;

    AmazonS3 s3Client;
    Uri selectedImageUri, selectedVideoUri;
    ImageView ivSelectedImage;
    VideoView vvSelectedVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize AWS S3 client
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Pool_Id", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.Region // Your region
        );

        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("Access_key", "Secret_key");
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_NORTH_1));

        ivSelectedImage = findViewById(R.id.ivSelectedImage);
        vvSelectedVideo = findViewById(R.id.vvSelectedVideo);
        Button btnSelectImage = findViewById(R.id.btnSelectImage);
        Button btnSelectVideo = findViewById(R.id.btnSelectVideo);
        Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        // Handle Image Selection Button Click
        btnSelectImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openImagePicker();
        });

        // Handle Video Selection Button Click
        btnSelectVideo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openVideoPicker();
        });

        // Handle Submit Button Click
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (selectedImageUri != null && selectedVideoUri != null) {
                uploadFileToS3(Uri.fromFile(new File(getPathFromUri(selectedImageUri))), "image");
                uploadFileToS3(Uri.fromFile(new File(getPathFromUri(selectedVideoUri))), "video");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please select an image and video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openImagePicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE);
    }

    private void openVideoPicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_PICK_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE) {
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                ivSelectedImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            } else if (requestCode == VIDEO_PICK_CODE) {
                selectedVideoUri = data.getData();
                vvSelectedVideo.setVideoURI(selectedVideoUri);
                vvSelectedVideo.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void uploadFileToS3(Uri fileUri, String category) {
        try {
            // Get InputStream from the file URI
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            if (inputStream == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to open input stream for the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Create metadata to handle file type and other info
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentType(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri));  // Set content type (e.g., image/jpeg)

            // Generate a unique file name if needed
            String fileName = category + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(fileUri);

            // Upload the file to S3
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("testbucket3557", fileName, inputStream, metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);

            // Close the input stream
            inputStream.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        String extension = "";
        String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
        if (mimeType != null) {
            String[] parts = mimeType.split("/");
            if (parts.length > 1) {
                extension = parts[1];  // Extract file extension
            }
        }
        return extension;
    }

    public String getPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            return filePath;
        } else {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }
}


This is my mainActivity.java code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         />




    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

And this is AndroidManifest.xml file
I tried to edit the permissions but nothing helped moreover. The specific error is shown in the image. The same error is for video
enter image description here
